# What is recovery mode?

Tags: boot

I notice that when I first turn on my pi, it says: "Hold down shift to run recovery mode".  What does this do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are using NOOBS.

Recovery mode lets you enter the NOOBS interface to do the following:

- Install selected operating systems onto your SD card.
- Edit configuration files for an operating system.
- Get online help (network required).
- Select the display language.
- Select the keyboard layout.
- Select the display mode    (HDMI, composite etc.).
- Exit NOOBS and reboot the Pi into the operating system boot menu.

See https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs