# Raspbian OS broken after "dist-upgrade". Fresh-start instructions sought

Tags: raspbian-stretch, noobs, pi-4

Rapsberry Pi 4 with Noobs & Rapsbian full installed. Was working perfectly, until I did an `apt-get dist-upgrade`. Now (after reboot) it seems the *window manager* is broken or not launched : symptoms, mouse can not interact with windows (move, resize, close etc. no work). Keyboard actions are *not* affected (Alt+F4 closes a window, e.g.)

I am willing to restart from zero, using Noobs, which I verified is working and accessible at boot time. Noobs is seeing the Rasbian - Full as "installed" and it has a chek-mark besides it.
How am I supposed to tell Noobs to zap the installed OS, repartition the card as might be necessary, download the official Raspbian for my Pi and start all over ?
Un-checking the mark of the "installed" OS did nothing, and I couldn't find a way to "remove" or "uninstall", whatever they might call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOOBS has a recovery option to trash everything you've done on your Raspbian system and start again (it gives you an unpatched system just like the day you started).

Hit or tap the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key during boot to activate the recovery menu.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/24855/94397

Comment: I had restarted to the Noobs recovery but had failed to find the "Install" button there. Doh ! For my defense, I have low sight and the fonts are minuscule : the Devs really should think "accessibility" and provide on-screen magnifier/loupe or some way to increase font size. Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong site to ask about [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) because few (if any) of the experienced uses use NOOBS. The general recommendation on this site is **NOT** to use NOOBS.

You should be able to re-install Raspbian from NOOBS by pressing the Shift key at the correct time during boot.

Did you `update` Raspbian BEFORE upgrade? The following command will update Raspbian.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Yes I did both and ended with a non functional window manager, probably repairable for an experienced Linux geek like yourself. I removed the "repair" option from my question in favor of the crudest "zap & start again" - though repair would have been interesting I thought mixing both would not have been made proper Stackexhange question.

Comment: @NimbUs I rarely bother attempting to repair broken OS - it is easier (and more reliable) restoring from backup.